# Record Insertion using Lightning,

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, record, database.insert

I need to insert a record to a custom object throught the lightning page that I have created. but i am getting the attached SS error.

Could any1 tell me what I am doing wrong ?

CMP:-

```
<aura:component controller="houseHoldServicesCtrl">      

    <aura:attribute name="Registration" type="Registration__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isMdlBxOpnLgn" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isMdlBxOpnReg" type="boolean" default="false"/>

    <!-- LOGIN MODAL BOX START -->

    <div class="RHS_button">         
        <lightning:button label="Login"
                          onclick="{!c.openModalBoxLgn}"
                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"
                          iconPosition="right"
                          />       

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isMdlBxOpnLgn}">            
            <!--###### MODAL BOX Start######--> 
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                              onclick="{!c.closeModalBox}"
                                              alternativeText="close"
                                              variant="bare-inverse"
                                              class="slds-modal__close"/>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Login Page</h2>
                    </header>

                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <c:houseHoldServices_Login/>
                    </div>  

                    <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning:button label="Login !"
                                          onclick=""
                                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                          
                                          /> 

                        <lightning:button label="Reset"
                                          onclick=""
                                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                          
                                          />

                        <lightning:button label="Go Back"
                                          onclick=""
                                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                          
                                          />
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

        </aura:if>
    </div>
    <!-- LOGIN MODAL BOX END -->   



    <!-- REGISTRATION MODAL BOX START -->   
    <div class="RHS_button">                    
        <lightning:button label="Register / SignUp"
                          onclick="{!c.openModalBoxReg}"
                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                        
                          />
    </div>   

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isMdlBxOpnReg}">            
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Start######--> 
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          onclick="{!c.closeModalBox}"
                                          alternativeText="close"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          class="slds-modal__close"/>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Registration Page</h2>
                </header>   

                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <lightning:input aura:id="EmaiL"

                                     value="{!v.Registration.EmaiL__c}"                          
                                     placeholder="Em@iL"/>

                    <lightning:input aura:id="MobileNumber"

                                     value="{!v.Registration.Mobile_Number__c}"                          
                                     placeholder="Mobile Number"/>

                    <lightning:input aura:id="Username"

                                     value="{!v.Registration.Username__c}"                         
                                     placeholder="Username"/> 

                    <lightning:input aura:id="Password"                         
                                     value="{!v.Registration.Password__c}"                         
                                     placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>  

                <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start ######-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button label="Submit to Register !"
                                      onclick="{!c.registerUser}"
                                      class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                          
                                      /> 

                    <lightning:button label="Reset"
                                      onclick=""
                                      class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                          
                                      />

                    <lightning:button label="Go Back"
                                      onclick=""
                                      class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                          
                                      />
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

    </aura:if>

    <!-- REGISTRATION MODAL BOX END -->    

    <div class="LHS_button">
        <lightning:button label="Contact Us"
                          onclick=""
                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"
                          iconPosition="right"
                          />  | 

        <lightning:button label="About Us"
                          onclick=""
                          class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"                      
                          /> 
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        header
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

clientSide Controller :-

```
 registerUser   :function(component,event,helper){
        debugger;        
        helper.regHelpr(component);
    }
```

---

helper:-

```
({
    regHelpr : function(component) {
        debugger;
        var strEmaiL        = component.find("EmaiL").get("v.value");
        var strMobileNumber = component.find("MobileNumber").get("v.value");
        var strUsername     = component.find("Username").get("v.value");
        var strPassword     = component.find("Password").get("v.value");

        var action = component.get("c.submit");
        action.setParams({ 
            "EmaiL"         :strEmaiL,
            "MobileNumber"  :strMobileNumber,
            "Username"      :strUsername,
            "Password"      :strPassword
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){            
            component.set("v.Registration",response.getReturnValue());            
        });

        component.set("v.isMdlBxOpnReg",false);        
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
})
```

---

serverSide Controller APEX CLASS

```
public class houseHoldServicesCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void submit(String EmaiL,String MobileNumber,String Username,String Password){

        Registration__c regstr = new Registration__c();

        regstr.EmaiL__c         = EmaiL;
        regstr.Mobile_N[enter image description here][1]umber__c    = MobileNumber;
        regstr.Username__c      = Username;
        regstr.Password__c      = Password;       

        Database.Insert(regstr);        

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Registration" attribute is null, so attempting to assign a value to the object results in a null reference error. Assign a default value:

```
<aura:attribute name="Registration" type="Registration__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Registration__c'}" />
```

Please note that Aura/Lightning/JavaScript is case sensitive, so pay attention to the value carefully.